# Carousel indicators doesn't work.I dont know why

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I cannot change images of carousel with indicators they are not working.I couldn't find what i am doing wrong.There is no css or js just bootstrap.When i click indicator doesn't happen anything just active slide visible.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/styles.css">


<!-- Start Img Slider -->
<div id="slide " class="carousel h-100 mw-100 " data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
        <li data-target="slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="slide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="slide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner img-fluid" role=listbox>
        <!-- slide 1 -->
        <div class="carousel-item active " style="background-image: url(images/team1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- slide 2 -->
        <div class="carousel-item  " style="background-image: url(images/team2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- slide 3 -->
        <div class="carousel-item  " style="background-image: url(images/team3.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--  end Img Slider -->

<script src="inc/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="inc/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

UPDATE SOLVED !!!

Just forget # at data-target

```html
    <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
        <li data-target="#slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these for indicator controls:

```
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

Please refer to this for more information/example:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/

Answer (score -1):

You have missed double quote (")
I believe your problem is simply this

```html
    <div class="carousel-inner img-fluid" role=listbox>
```

Replace with this

```html
    <div class="carousel-inner img-fluid" role="listbox">
```

Comment: It's best practice to wrap attribute values in quotes, but it's completely valid to omit the quotes. Both examples in your answer are valid. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#unquoted

Comment: The problem is not whether it is conceptually valid or not.
The problem is the Bootstrap javascript which does not recognize the attribute and generating an error, blocking the execution of the script.

Comment: `role="listbox"` and `role=listbox` are equivalent for the purpose of javascript.